# MS Outlook 2010 .pst behavior

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

In previous versions of Outlook, if you made the pst the default location on the Data Files tab of account settings, your mail in your mailbox inbox would move to your pst inbox.  This is not automatically happening in Outlook 2010.

Anyone have any ideas how to make it happen?

Debbie

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the location to default, close Outlook (this is what I think you may be missing), give it a minute to make the changes, and then reopen it.

Comment: No, I have closed and reopened and it still has not forwarded.